# Java: How can I time simple events to happen after X seconds?

Tags: java

I'm playing around with Java and I've got myself a class for an NPC in a game. One method is called when they collide with another object:

```
public void collided_in_to(Entity ent) {

    if(ent.equals(game.player)) {
        this.speak = "Ouch!";
    }

}
```

What I want to do, which I figured was going to be simple, is set `this.speak` to `""` after a given amount of seconds. Coming from a web background, I was looking for an equivalent of Javascripts `setTimeout()`.

I've tried using various timer snippets, such as using Swing timers, but in that case it seemed like every timer would call the same `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method, and so with multiple timers for different events I had no way to differentiate between them. Others used inline anonymous classes, but then I have no way to pass non-final parameters to it.

Is there something I'm missing for this use case, where I want very small simple things to happen after a set time? (Instance method called, variable set, etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about writing you own simple Timer? I would think of something like this :

```
public class Timer {

long start = 0;
long delay;

public Timer(long delay) {
    this.delay = delay;
}

public void start() {
    this.start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public boolean isExpired() {
    return (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.start) > this.delay;
}

}
```

Then instantiate the Timer class as a class member and call start() when you want to start the timer.

In your method you call

```
public void collided_in_to(Entity ent) {

    if(ent.equals(game.player)) {
        if(this.timer.isExpired()) this.speak = "";
        else this.speak = "Ouch!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like just what I need, I didn't really consider something so simple as I figured it must exist already. I'll have to come up with a nicer way of handling many timers on a single class, rather than a giant list of if statements for each timer, but it gets me started.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a [game loop](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/writing_the_game_loop.htm) you could simply make a *seconds passed verification*.

Comment: I'm using slick2d so the game loop is kind of taken care of. I'm not sure how I'd get actual seconds from the delta which is currently given in the update() methods.

Comment: You could set a `timeToSet = new Date() plus seconds` (don't remember the sintax), and then, for verification, compare `new Date()` with `timeToSet`.

Comment: @Tom, you aren't obligated to use the delta, **I think**, just use [currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) to get the startingTime, and test that value constantly against the currentTime. Just like `if(startingTime + 3000 >= currentTime){//do it}`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered threads? Thread.sleep() can be used fairly effectively to time it.

Comment: Won't that sleep the whole program if there are no separate threads currently? To be clear, I do want the rest of the program to continue while the timer is going.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` works if it's another different thread that sleeps until time is reached. In that case you should do something like `new Thread() { public void run() { sleep; setvar; } }`. But it uses a thread only for the verification, which in your context (game loop used) is not neccesary.

Comment: I guess I wasn't really clear. But as @helios put it, you should make it an anonymous local class. Keep in mind that `sleep()` is very inaccurate for smaller time values, and the `java.util.concurrent` package might be a better option.